# Is it possible to suppress a TaskCancelledException using an ExceptionFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception, async-await

In our C# Web API app, we are having an issue where our event logs are being polluted by TaskCancelledExceptions. These can be thrown for any number of reasons, including the user closing the browser/tab before an async operation completes. As we have plenty of other custom exceptions that are thrown when specific things happen, we have decided just to suppress TaskCancelledExceptions completely.

We have a common base class from which all controller classes inherit, into which we have put a number of existing exception filters. However, all of these filters seem to **do** something (throwing a predefined HttpResponseException), whereas I just want to stop a TaskCancelledException from propagating up the chain.

Here's my empty filter attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
internal sealed class TaskCancelledExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext != null && actionExecutedContext.Exception is TaskCanceledException)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What can I put in that if statement to stop the exception from going any further?

Is this even possible/the best way to go about this?